# Is it feasible to travel daily from Gavà to Barcelona?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, spain, barcelona

We are planning a 5 day trip to Barcelona and due to a limited budget we were thinking of staying in Gavà and then travelling to Barcelona, practically every morning. Do you consider this as feasible ? Is Gavà included in the Barcelona Card ? Or do you recommend a better solution ?

Comment: What's your budget? I'd be surprised if you couldn't get a hostel in Barcelona for a decent rate; there were plenty when I was there

Comment: Whether Gavà is included in the Barcelona card is best asked as a separate question.

Comment: Well we're students who have just graduated, trying to keep it as cheap as possible

Comment: if you haven't already, check hostelbookers.com.  I stayed in a great hostel downtown. You could also try couchsurfing.org.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it's only twenty kilometres from Barcelona, so from that point of view, yeah it's feasible.  I've done a similar thing in the past for Valencia; staying just outside of the city.  It'll take you about 25-30 minutes to drive to the center of Barcelona from Gavà.

Gavà is also very close to the airport, which may be handy depending on how you are arriving.

But consider - if you weren't planning on hiring a car (or don't have one), then you're adding the cost of a car rental, insurance and petrol to your accommodation (as well as using an hour of your time each day) to stay out of the city you were trying to visit.  This also restricts your night time activities if you're planning on drinking.

I'd be surprised if you couldn't find somewhere in Barcelona to stay which works out the same price as commuting from Gavà.

**Bus**

If you're not using a car, and want to use a bus to get into Barcelona, ten bus routes link Gavà to Barcelona, surrounding towns and the most important neighbouring places. For more information contact the Autobusos MOHN bus company, or [check the timetables on their website](http://www.gavaciutat.net/eng/asp/setrans1.asp).  It would appear they run every 45-60 minutes, depending on the day of the week, although evidently my *Castellano* is not good enough to find how long it takes.

Comment: Also, in the car option you left out the question of finding parking space in Barcelona. And paying for it, which isn't cheap. On the public transport page you can check how long it takes on http://www.emt.cat/Principales/BusquedaTrayecto.aspx   Seems that it's about 50 minutes bus ride.

Answer (score 10):

It's perfectly feasible, and a lot of people from Gavà (and towns further away) work in Barcelona.

[It takes about 30 minutes by train to Plaça de Catalunya and there are several trains every hour](http://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/horaris//cercador/?origenCerca=Gav%C3%A0&origen=71706&destiCerca=Barcelona-Pla%C3%A7a%20de%20Catalunya&desti=78805&dataViatge=18%2F10%2F2016&horaIni=17&lang=en&cercaRodalies=true). If your accommodation in Gavà is by the beach (Gavà Mar) then you will be quite away from the station, but there are buses from Gavà Mar to Barcelona.

Furthermore, for transport fares purposes Gavà is in the same transport area as Barcelona, so a trip from Gavà to anywhere in Barcelona costs exactly the same as a trip from one place within Barcelona to another (about 1 euro with a 10 trip card).

And I definitely wouldn't recommend to hire a car to do the journey from Gavà to Barcelona. Traffic is very difficult in working days and there is no free parking in most of Barcelona, so if you are going to spend the day in Barcelona parking the car for the whole day can get very expensive.

In the end, I must disagree with Mark Mayo's statement that he would be surprised "if you couldn't find somewhere in Barcelona to stay which works out the same price as commuting from Gavà." I would be surprised if accommodation in Gavà weren't cheaper than in Barcelona or at least better for the same price, although I must admit that I have no experience with hotels in Barcelona because I already live here.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem to lodge in Gavà, especially for people who are looking to save money on .
Barcelona Card is not valid for transportation around the area, however, other transportation cards (such as T-10) does valid.
If you plan to travel during the morning in Barcelona - I wouldn't rent a car (like others suggested here), it's pointless and you can travel quite easily by train or bus. The ride should take around 30-55 minutes (direction) and there are night Bus as well.
On the same subject, regarding Barcelona Card - I recommend to seriously consider whether you need to order the card or not.
From My experience - it is not always advantageous for all tourists, especially not for those who are looking for a low budget trip.